# pushing to array on mongodb now works

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am newby programmer. 
I use form that sends data to "/publishdAds". I have used it as router in the server.
When writing this:

```
router.post("/", function(req, res) {
  MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
    if (err) throw err;
    db.collection("jobs").update({"email" : req.body.jobLoggedIn}, {$push: {"ads":  {req.body.adData}}}, function(err, result) {
      if (err) throw err;
      console.log("1 document inserted");
      db.close();
    });
  });
});
```

I am getting this error:

```
db.collection("jobs").update({"email" : req.body.jobLoggedIn}, {$push: {"ads":  {req.body.adData}}}, function(err, result) {
                                                                                          ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token .
    at createScript (vm.js:56:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:97:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:542:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\EYAL\web\fe\angular\jobsFinderProject\server\app.js:14:63)
```

I have written similar code for inserting, and it works.

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the curly brackets around

```
{req.body.adData}
```

It is syntactically incorrect because curly brackets expect pairs of `key: value`, or a simple (can not contain dots) name `name` which is a synonym of `name: name`.